# OpenLDAP proxy AD showing empty tree

Tags: active-directory, proxy, openldap

I'm using OpenLDAP (in a docker container) mainly for two purposes:

1.) Having a local tree which actually stores my technical users.
2.) Proxy specific queries to my corporate active directory just to retrieve information (I don't want to modify something).

So far so good. I've found several tutorials in the internet which described how to proxy queries from an openldap to an active directory and finally I used this configuration (for my OpenLDAP) to configure the proxy:

```
dn: cn=module{0},cn=config
changetype: modify
add: olcModuleLoad
olcModuleLoad: {2}back_ldap

dn: olcDatabase={2}ldap,cn=config
changetype: add
objectClass: olcDatabaseConfig
objectClass: olcLDAPConfig
olcDatabase: {2}ldap
olcDbURI: ldap://my_corporate_ad:389
olcSuffix: dc=my,dc=corporate,dc=ad,dc=com
olcDbRebindAsUser: TRUE
olcDbChaseReferrals: TRUE
```

After setup I'm able to connect to the local tree and it works like expected. But when I try to connect to the OpenLDAP with the proxy credentials/base dn then I'm able to login but I cannot see any tree/entries. An ldapsearch just gives me zero results if I query for objectclass=*.

When I look at the logs from the openldap then it shows me this output:

```
56ebba59 conn=1007 fd=23 ACCEPT from IP=100.30.407.19:15313 (IP=172.17.0.3:389)
56ebba59 conn=1007 op=0 BIND dn="cn=dockers2eu,cn=Users,dc=my,dc=corporate,dc=ad,dc=com" method=128
56ebba59 conn=1007 op=0 BIND dn="cn=dockers2eu,cn=Users,dc=my,dc=corporate,dc=ad,dc=com" mech=SIMPLE ssf=0
56ebba59 conn=1007 op=0 RESULT tag=97 err=0 text=
56ebba59 conn=1007 op=1 SRCH base="dc=my,dc=corporate,dc=ad,dc=com" scope=1 deref=0 filter="(objectClass=*)"
56ebba59 conn=1007 op=1 SRCH attr=objectclass
Unable to chase referral "ldap://bkabkzasdh" (-1: Can't contact LDAP server)
Unable to chase referral "ldap://asdfjkasdja" (-1: Can't contact LDAP server)
Unable to chase referral "ldap://my.corporate.ad.com/CN=Configuration,DC=my,DC=corporate,DC=ad,DC=com??base" (-1: Can't contact LDAP server)
56ebba8f conn=1007 op=1 SEARCH RESULT tag=101 err=0 nentries=0 text=
56ebbacb conn=1007 op=2 SRCH base="dc=my,dc=corporate,dc=ad,dc=com" scope=0 deref=0 filter="(objectClass=*)"
56ebbacb conn=1007 op=2 SEARCH RESULT tag=101 err=0 nentries=0 text=
```

What I see here is that he can't chase the referrals. That should be okay because I just want to retrieve the information stored locally on the AD.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first thing is to make sure your ldapsearch is correct.  This will determine if the problem is with the query or your LDAP configuration.

Change the ldap host in your ldapsearch command to be -H ldap://my_corporate_ad:389 to query AD directly.  If that returns results, then your search is valid.  If not, get that working before reattempting against OpenLDAP.

In your LDAPConfig you may want to add appropriate olcAccess lines, though I'm not sure that's actually causing your issue.

Comment: Thank you very much. Like you said, the problem was that I didn't mentioned olcAccess. After I added "olcAccess: * by * read" to my ldapmodify it worked.